# Communicating with processes in the same host using internet sockets?

Tags: linux, sockets, ipc, embedded-linux

I am building a message layer for processes running on an embedded Linux system. I am planing to use sockets. This system might be ported to different operating systems down the road so portability is a concern. Performance is below portability in priority order.

I have a few questions regarding my way forward.

1. I am thinking of using **internet sockets over TCP/IP** for this communication between **local processes** for the sake of portability. Is there any reason that I should not do that and use domain sockets?
2. Does it really improve the portability when using internet sockets instead of domain sockets?
3. If this is indeed the way forward, can you point me in the right direction (how to use ports for each process etc.) with some online resources?

Comment: How portable - more than posix systems?  What kind of communication?  Is it something suitable for shared memory?

Comment: Yes, beyond POSIX family. Using sockets is pretty much decided by the architect, if there isn't a very strong argument against it.

Comment: I suspect you are right.  You could wrap native facilities behind a common interface but if you don't have a compelling reason maybe it isn't worth the effort.  The code difference between domain sockets and tcp is almost zilch, for instance.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggested readings; I am not clear on the details; how to select port numbers etc. There's not much literature I could find on this.

Comment: A lot of people like [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) which is pretty basic but clearly written and free.  I think most of his domain socket is in another guide under [unix sockets](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/index.html).  There is nothing much special about port numbers.  Servers usually use a number in the lower range (but above 1024 unless you are root) for their listening port.  Clients usually just take the port returned by default.

Comment: The reference: Stevens (http://unpbook.com)

Comment: @alk, have they ever updated that one?  My copy is from 1990 and some of the chapters cover stuff that is pretty much irrelevant today.  I usually go w/ UNPv1

Comment: I think the current edition is the 3rd one. @Duck  (as per the link in my comment)